# How to sort files according to the first two characters in the last word PATH

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, sed

Please advice How to sort files ( with sort command ),  according to the first two characters in the last word PATH

```
   /dir/dir/dir/LAST_WORD_PATH
```

Example:

if the following PATH is

```
      /Config/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fSE-TMOLE.txt
```

so the last word PATH should be

```
    fSE-TMOLE.txt
```

the target is to sort the first two character in the "last word PATH"

then the two first characters are ( from **fSE-TMOLE.txt**  )

```
    fS
```

Full example

before sort

```
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dzs Bulia Mole.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fAE-TMOLE.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dos Bulia Mole.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Bgaia Mobile/Fustoer files/Backup/Cos Buia Mole-2.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/VFONE Roia/Cbdne.ro.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/TEKOM SRJA/IELOM SRJA.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/VP Moe/Bobile.txt
```

after sort

```
     /Config/EMA/M5/VP Moe/Bobile.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/VFONE Roia/Cbdne.ro.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Bgaia Mobile/Fustoer files/Backup/Cos Buia Mole-2.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dos Bulia Mole.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dzs Bulia Mole.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fAE-TMOLE.txt
     /Config/EMA/M5/TEKOM SRJA/IELOM SRJA.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick makes it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="|"} {print $NF, $0}' file | sort -fk1 | cut -d'|' -f2-
/Config/EMA/M5/VP Moe/Bobile.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/VFONE Roia/Cbdne.ro.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Bgaia Mobile/Fustoer files/Backup/Cos Buia Mole-2.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dos Bulia Mole.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dzs Bulia Mole.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fAE-TMOLE.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/TEKOM SRJA/IELOM SRJA.txt
```

As the last filed is not a fixed position, let's copy it to the front of the line, sort based on that and then remove it.

Note `sort -f` is to ignore case and `-k1` to sort based on first column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f
do
   b=$(basename "$f")   # Get basic name of file without path
   b2=${b:0:2}          # Extract first 2 letters
   echo $b2:$f          # Output for awk to read with colon separator
done < file | sort -f | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A very reliable way of doing it with `perl`:

```
#! /bin/bash 

input=/tmp/file
perl -F/ -anle '
    $F[$#F] =~ /^(..)/; 
    $key="\U$1"; 
    $h{$key}=[] unless exists $h{$key}; 
    push ${h{$key}},$_; 

    END{
        foreach $key (sort keys %h){
            foreach( @{$h{$key}}){
                print "$_"
            }
        }
    }' $input
```

**Explanation:**

It creates a hash using the first two characters of the last field converted to upper case  as its key. The hash lools like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'IE' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/TEKOM SRJA/IELOM SRJA.txt'
                  ],
          'CO' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Bgaia Mobile/Fustoer files/Backup/Cos Buia Mole-2.txt'
                  ],
          'DZ' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dzs Bulia Mole.txt'
                  ],
          'CB' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/VFONE Roia/Cbdne.ro.txt'
                  ],
          'FA' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fAE-TMOLE.txt'
                  ],
          'DO' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dos Bulia Mole.txt'
                  ],
          'BO' => [
                    '     /Config/EMA/M5/VP Moe/Bobile.txt'
                  ]
        };
```

Then we sort the hash based on key and print values.

**PS.** This solution accounts for cases of duplicated keys as it creates an array for each key. It should also be faster than any provided solution up to now as it all done all in perl there are not shell forks.

Comment: @maihabunash it could be shorter but the way it stands is already hard enough to read `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file names don't contain tabs, you can do this:

```
cat files | sed s/.*/\&\\t\&/ | sed -r s/.*\\/\(..\).*\\t/\\1/ | sort | sed s/...//

/Config/EMA/M5/VP Moe/Bobile.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/VFONE Roia/Cbdne.ro.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Bgaia Mobile/Fustoer files/Backup/Cos Buia Mole-2.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dos Bulia Mole.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/Cmo Buria Mobile/dzs Bulia Mole.txt
/Eonfig/EMA/M5/Hatki Tekom/Customer Files/fAE-TMOLE.txt
/Config/EMA/M5/TEKOM SRJA/IELOM SRJA.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also

```
sed  -r 's@^(/.*/)(.*)@\2|\1\2@g' filename | sort | sed -r 's/^[^|]+.(.*)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sed 's|.*/\(..\).*|\1&|' file | sort -sk1,1.2 | sed 's/..//'
```

Extract the first 2 characters of the "last word" and prepend to each line. Sort using the prepended key preserving position using stabilize sort. Remove the prepended key.